# getting content of push notification (android)?

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification

After 2 days of struggle, I have to ask for help.

**GOAL:** concatenate the old message with the new message.

**QUESTION:** How can I extract the text from the notification?

**NOTE:** the notification is updated by the same bundle and the same id.

this code creates a notification when a message is received:

```
    private void showNotification(String username, String msg) 
{    
    String title = getString(R.string.msg_notification_title) ;     
    String text =username + ": " +msg;
    if (firstTime) {

        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentTitle(title); 
        firstTime = false;
    }
    else {
            // messages concatination should take place here
    }

    mBuilder.setContentText(text);

    mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 });

    mBuilder.setLights(Color.CYAN, 3000, 3000);

    mBuilder.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" +R.raw.notification_ring));


    Intent i = new Intent(this, Messaging.class);
    i.putExtra(FriendInfo.USERNAME, username);
    i.putExtra(MessageInfo.MESSAGETEXT, msg);   
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP); 


    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

    stackBuilder.addParentStack(Messaging.class);

    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(i);

    PendingIntent contentIntent =stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent); 

    NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

    String[] events = new String[6];

    inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("Event tracker details:");

    for (int s=0; s < events.length; s++) {

        inboxStyle.addLine(events[s]);
    }

    mBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);

    mNM.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
}
```

thanks in advance.